# Drag and move JPanels in a group of JPanels

Tags: java, swing

There is a group of 10 JPanels which are placed in a GridLayout. Now I want to drag one JPanel(for instance panel1) and place it over another JPanel (for instance panel2) and move panel2 to left or right and place panel1 in panel2 position. I am able to drag JPanel using drag option, but I am not able to drop it at the required position. I need some help in moving panels in drop location.
Sorry, if my question is not clear. Hope you understand.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could check for collisions between the dragged panel and the others, then switch positions when a collision occurs...but there's probably a better way of doing this.

Comment: Fernando: Do we have a method to check for collisions? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Yeah, panel.getBounds() returns a *Rectangle* object, which you can use to call rectangle.insersects(anotherRectangle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, but like i said, there's probably a better way:

```
public JPanel getPanelColliding(JPanel dragPanel, JPanel[] panels)
{
   Rectangle rDrag = dragPanel.getBounds();

   for (JPanel panel : panels){
     if (panel == dragPanel) continue;

     Rectangle r = panel.getBounds();
     if (r.insersects(rDrag))
         return r;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Then in your *drag* listener you can call it and swap panel locations if *getPanelColliding()* is not null. I didn't test this, but it should work!

Comment: Thanks Fernando, will try and get back.

Comment: It is surely a start to solve the problem, but I agree with you that there might be a better way.

Comment: You should swap positions by the way, not JPanels. Maybe by *setLocation()*

Answer (score 0):

Did something similar to this, but moving around `SWT Control(s)`.

My controls were next to each other (no space between them), so when I drop a **control1**, it will know on which **control2** it's being dropped (with `control2.getBounds().contains(dropPoint)`).

After that, I map the `dropPoint` to **control2**, and find out if the `dropPoint` is on the left or right of **control2**'s width. Then I simply move **control1** with `moveAbove(control2)` or `moveBelow(control2)`.

Finally, I call `container.layout()` (**container** is the parent for the controls) to notify its children that the layout has changed, and the children move.